# AngularJS directive that contains ng-bind-html directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want this piece of code

```
<test data="myObject"></test>
```

to be rendered as

```
<p>raw html code that is stored inside myObject.html</p>
```

My directive

```
module.directive('test', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<p ng-bind-html="__what_to_do_here__?"></p>',
        scope: {
            // This object has a html propery which contains raw html.
            data: '='
        }
    };
});
```

How can i pass the raw html variable to the ngBindHtml directive in my template?

Comment: `ng-bind-html="data.html"` - does that work?

Comment: nope - that's why i'm asking

Answer (score 1):

Did you include ngSanitize? I think it is required to be able to render html from a variable.
You can find more information about ng-bind-html here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml (will also link you to ngSanitize)

Comment: Thanks for the replies, this is my first answer. And as I don't have enough reputation, I couldn't ask the question as a comment... Will try to make it better next time